# Begin a Sprite C++ DirectX

Tags: c++, oop, directx

Any idea why is this happening?
[image]

In my Main.cpp, I just called the function like this:

```
    Character *Police;
    Police = new Character;
    Police->Initialize("Police.png", 50.0f, 50.0f, 64.0f, 63.5f);


    MSG Msg;
        while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            while (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if (Msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;
                TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                DispatchMessage(&Msg);
            }
            Inputs->GetInput();
            Graphic->ClearBegin();

            Police->Transform();
            Police->Begin();
            Police->Draw();
            Police->End();

            Graphic->EndPresent();
        }
```

I dont get what is this exception is about..

Comment: Looks like your sprite pointer is not initialized !

Comment: I did I guess.. in my header i called `LPD3DXSPRITE Sprite;` then in the cpp constructor, I set it to NULL `Sprite = NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

Your Sprite pointer is not initialized.  You see it on the bottom of your screenshot (Sprite is NULL).

Trying to call a function for a null objject results in an access violation.

Consider initializing your sprite with [`D3DXCreateSprite()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before using it.

Comment: `void Character::Initialize(string image, float PosX, float PosY, float CenterX, float CenterY)
{
 D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(PULL->getD3ddev(), image.c_str(), &Texture);
 D3DXCreateSprite(PULL->getD3ddev(), &Sprite);
 SpritePos = D3DXVECTOR2(PosX, PosY);
 SpriteCenter = D3DXVECTOR2(CenterX, CenterY);
}`
Is this how it suppose to be?

Comment: Have you checked that `D3DXCreateSprite(PULL->getD3ddev(), &Sprite)` returns `S_OK` ?

Comment: Yup. Just tested it using `HRESULT hr;` And there is an error on creating the sprite..What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Difficult to say.  It could be that you provide a wrong device.  But the structure of your programme seems strange.  Normally you don't call these fucntions directly from main() nor from within the message loop. Are you sure you've performed all the windows and DirectX initialisation sequence before trying to create the sprite ?

Comment: Yup I did. It run normally if i create the sprite directly in main. But when I export all of it to a new character class, this happens.

Comment: In my direct3d9 class, this is the function to return the device.
`LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 Direct3D9::getD3ddev()
{
 return this->d3ddev;
}`

Comment: Ok, but your d3ddev is initalized somewhere with a CreateDeivec() call.  Have you checked there that the result was ok ?

Comment: Yes. There do not have any errors. Since I am able to call the same initialize function in main.